# pre defined relationship based on node property in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, relationships

I need to define a relationship between two nodes. Have a company and people node, company node has property called id and people node has property called company_id.

So when ever a new people and company are added, do I need to create relationships each time.

Is there an option in neo4j, to pre-define that id of company and company_id of people are the property to match ?, and for every new entry if a matching is found create the relationship automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Nope there is no built-in function for that.

The fact is that in graph databases, a relationship is replacing the "company_id" property.

On the application level, you can adapt your queries to create the relationship whenever a people node is added in the database

```
MERGE (p:People)-[:WORKS_AT]->(c:Company)
```

Chris

Answer (score 3):

You can run a query regularly like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE has(p.company_id)
MATCH (c:Company {id:p.company_id})
MERGE (p)-[:WORKS_AT]->(c)
REMOVE p.company_id;
```

In a server/kernel extension or embedded code you can also register a tx-commit listener that does exactly that.

You could also use something like an external listener on the [GraphAware change-feed extension](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/08/27/graphaware-neo4j-changefeed.html) to trigger running that query.

Comment: https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/runtime for more info on how to quickly define a GraphAware runtime module to create a relationship between the company and person when either is added to the graph